# Trying to run a "uber clone" from github in react native ( vs code )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, github, android-emulator, clone

warn Multiple Podfiles were found: DriverApp/ios/Podfile,MyCabApp/ios/Podfile,UberClone/DriverApp/ios/Podfile,UberClone/UserApp/ios/Podfile,UserApp/ios/Podfile. Choosing DriverApp/ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/configuration.md
error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

this is the error now.

I tried running my react native app which is basicallay a clonme of uber from github but it is not running .

Answer (score 0):

The warning about multiple Podfiles should not prevent you from building the app. However, I've submitted a pull request to address this issue for new apps.

It's possible that the problem is due to a misconfiguration of the environment. To confirm, please try manually installing the pods by following these steps:

1. Navigate to your app folder in the Terminal
2. Run the command `cd ios`
3. Run `bundle install` (you only need to do this once)
4. Execute `bundle exec pod install`

This should provide us with more insight into the problem you're experiencing. Thank you for your cooperation.